# Assignment function to function

Tags: c++, function

Please explain me why the code below doesn't work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo() { return 1; }
int bar() { return 2; }

void ass()
{
    foo=bar;
}

int main()
{
    ass()
}
```

The following error

> ```
> test.cpp: In function ‘void ass()’:
> test.cpp:8:8: error: assignment of function ‘int foo()’
> test.cpp:8:8: error: cannot convert ‘int()’ to ‘int()’ in assignment
> ```

caused.

Comment: Why do you think it should work?

Comment: It doesn't work because it makes no sense. Could you explain what you want `*foo=*bar` to do? As the error says, you're trying to assign to a function, which isn't allowed. Assignment only works for object (data) types.

Comment: How do you even expect something like this to work ?

Comment: @MikeSeymour I've updated my post. I'm trying to do that the name `foo` denote another function.

Comment: The language received a few quasi-FP features with C++11, but things haven't gone that far!

Answer (score 3):

You must use a function pointer. You cannot assign to the function itself.

```
int(*baz)() = &foo;
baz();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
typedef int (*int_funcptr_void)(void);
```

then, you can simply:

```
int foo() { return 1; }
int bar() { return 2; }

int_funcptr_void func;

void ass()
{
    func = (int_funcptr_void)foo;
}

int main()
{
    ass(); //you also forgot a semicolon here, but nice naming
    //then, we can call it:
    printf("%d\n", func());
}
```

and get this:

```
hydrogen:tmp phyrrus9$ ./a.out
1
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign  `function` to `function`, as you can not assign `int` to `int`. Think naturally, you assign an **int variable** to another **int variable**, which means you are assigning *rvalue* of the second variable to the *lvalue*(address) of the first one. Same rule for function, you can assign a **function object** to another **function object**. The difference is, *function is code*, not data, but it has an address ( the starting point). So assigning function to one another generally means assigning the address of the function to a variable which can hold an address, i.e. a function pointer.

```
void f(){}

typedef void(*pF)(); //typedef for easy use

pf foo;  //create a function pointer object
foo = &f; //assign it the address of the function
```